# Is it possible to access Neo4J graph database with server public ip

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to access Neo4J graph database every body.

I tried localhost and router level working fine  but I want give  remotely to access every one so install this neo4j in Windows server R2.

My issue is, I want to give URL with public IP address like `http://MyPublicIp:7474/browser/`  but browse this URL getting site can't reachable.

Comment: Yes it's absolutely possible ,I am going it with my db.

Comment: @ mohit sharma can you please tell those configurations to set. I set   dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0 and tried with public ip not getting "this site can’t be reached" its working for router level

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable listening for non-local connections. And of course the port needs to be open in your firewall.

Depending on version of neo4j you use it might be:

3.0.x (you need to do this bor http, https and bolt separately):

```
dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474
```

3.1.x/3.2.x:
For all connectors

```
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

For single connector

```
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474
```

For more see the [Neo4j operations manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/#_defaults_for_addresses).

Comment: i set like dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0 and my URL  with public IP "http://**.**.****.**:7474/browser/" getting This site can’t be reached